# How to do selenium tasks using requests in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

My question is I want to get the result from this website [Website](http://pu.edu.pk/home/results_show/7471).

I don't want to do this with any Web Browser. Is there any way? Thanks.

The steps for getting results are :
Enter the roll number in the text.
Press the submit Button.

Then the webpage reloads and the result appears.

Comment: Can you put a dummy `roll no` here? poori class ka result nikalo gey?

Comment: 45218 it's the roll number

Comment: what data do you want from the site cgpa or other data also

Comment: I want everything.

Comment: using requests you can get the result quickly but you have to get specific fields since it doesn't show webpage

Comment: please provide me solution If you can. The website link is all yours.

Comment: using requests you can get the html of the entire page